# How to use to sed to remove ^M NOT preceded by < in a file

Tags: sed

I've found a lot of good sed examples here, which brought me to:
sed -r 's/(\b|[^'>'])'^M')/\1''/g' test.txt
 but I'm still not getting the desired result.  I'm trying to parse an XML file, where each line should end in >^M, but there are a few random ^M in the middle of lines.  Can I use sed to remove these, but leave the desired ones in place?
I've tried a number of variations with quotes and double quotes around the > and ^M but to no avail.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you enter `^M` correctly? On most add shells, you have to type Ctrl+V, then Ctrl+M. Else, `sed` should recognize `\r` escape sequence.

Comment: yeah adding a sample would help and `perl` would be better suited as it supports lookarounds